# how to remove compiler optimizations in java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, optimization, compiler-optimization

as titles says ,

i'd to take optimizations off  because i want to create a bytecode ,class file, that will be an input to other program. This class file will be used for testing the program , and is assumed to be unoptimized.

thanks,

Comment: Even optimized java compilation produces a classfile of bytecode.

Comment: yea , i want the bytecode , just without any optimizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is only one (potential) compiler optimizations to turn off.  That is the optimization that inlines the JSRs used by older compilers to reduce code size for `finally` clauses.  And this is only a potential optimization to turn off ... because for later JVMs the optimization is mandatory.

See [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_options.htm) for details.

Apart from that, there are no bytecode optimizations that you can turn off.  But don't worry ... most of the serious optimizations are performed by the JIT compiler.

Comment: That page also mentions not removing unused variables, and including line numbers and local variable names.

Comment: @Stephen Dunne - yes, but those optimizations are all in the "off" position by default, which is why I didn't mention them.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be much in the way of optimization to worry about. [This page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm) lists the eclipse java compiler options.